How to remove sunday and holdiay hours in between two given datetime
Any suggestions or ways to approach to calculating idleTime? For the given two date time.
Cases for I'm struggling to solve,

If the start Date is Sunday or Holiday: remaining Sunday hours + morning of the next day(till 6: 30 AM ) should not be considered to idle time.

if the end Date is Sunday or Holiday , the time of the day must not be considered to idle time.


The code that I have mentioned below is not accurate.
Expected output for:
startTime = "2024-05-05T12:00:00Z"; // Assuming UTC format <br>
endTime = "2024-05-06T13:00:00Z";   // Assuming UTC format

o/p => 7 hours <br>
difference hours ( endTime - startTime )= 25.000 ,  sundayHours =  18, differenceHours - sundayHours - holidayHours = 7

What I have tried so far,
function calculateIdleTimeExcludingSundaysAndHolidays(startTime, endTime) {
var startUtc = new Date(startTime).getTime();
var endUtc = new Date(endTime).getTime();
var totalIdleTime = 0;

    for (var currentTime = startUtc; currentTime < endUtc; currentTime += 60 * 1000) { // Increment by 1 minute
        var currentDateTime = new Date(currentTime);
        if (currentDateTime.getUTCDay() !== 0 /* Not Sunday */ ) {
            totalIdleTime += 1; // 1 minute in seconds
        }
    }
    
    return totalIdleTime;

}


// Example usage
var startTime = "2024-05-13T12:00:00Z"; // Assuming UTC format
var endTime = "2024-05-15T13:00:00Z";   // Assuming UTC format

var idleTimeInMinutes = calculateIdleTimeExcludingSundaysAndHolidays(startTime, endTime);<br>
console.log("Idle time in minutes (excluding Sundays and holidays):", idleTimeInMinutes);


you should consider currentTime > 6:30 AM when conditioning your accumulator


Any suggestions or ways to approach to calculating idleTime? For the
given two date time.
Blockquote

Yes,Inorder to do this consider the following steps

Check end date is Sunday/holiday or not

If end date is sunday/holiday ignore it in the calculation

Now if Start date is sunday/holiday move to Monday 6.30

Find out the difference between two dates in minutes


Now Lets do it
1. Check if the end date is Sunday or not
   endDateIsSunday=endDate.getDay()===0||isHoliday(endDate);

2. If end date is Sunday ignore it in the calculation
   if(endDateIsSunday){
      endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()-1);//move to last Saturday
      //now move to sat 23.59  
      endDate.setHours(23);
      endDate.setMinutes(59);
    }

3.Now if the Start date is sunday move to Monday 6.30
     startDateIsSunday=startDate.getDay()===0||isHoliday(startDate);

     if(startDateIsSunday){
        //move to Monday 6.30
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
        startDate.setHours(6);
        startDate.setMinnutes(30);
     }

4.  find out the difference between the two dates in minutes
let diffinminute= (+endDate-+startDate)*1000/60;

At this point I am not sure how you decide a day is a holiday so for above solution its up to you to deinfe isHoliday method, but yet the code will remain the same
I hope this will help :)
